# Retrieve last row values for specific columns to send an email

Tags: google-apps-script

[image: Google Sheet Data]

I want to retrieve CPC and Spend column values of the last row and send that email on a daily basis. I have successfully retrieved CPC but I am unable to do it for spend column.

Code.gs

```
function sendEmail () {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = ss.getLastRow();
var data = ss.getRange(lr,3);
var values = data.getValues();
Logger.log(values);

var message = "Today CPC is " + values + "and spend is " ;
var email = "xyz@gmail.com";
var subject = "CPC Today"
MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject, message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, the value is retrieved from only one column. I thought that this is the reason for your issue. So in this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var data = ss.getRange(lr,3);
var values = data.getValues();
Logger.log(values);

var message = "Today CPC is " + values + "and spend is " ;
```

#### To:

```
var [[cpc, , spend]] = ss.getRange(lr, 3, 1, 3).getValues();
var message = "Today CPC is " + cpc + " and spend is " + spend;
```

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. Just for my understanding. ss.getRange(lr, 3, 1, 3) - What does this last number 3 signifies. I am asking because Spend is coming under coloumn number 5..

Comment: @Arif Ahmed Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Just for my understanding. ss.getRange(lr, 3, 1, 3) - What does this last number 3 signifies.`, in this case, `3` of the last argument means that number of columns. In your Spreadsheet, when `ss.getRange(lr, 3, 1, 3)` is converted to a1Notation, it's "C6:E6" when the last row is `6`. From this range, the values of `3.978421, 307, 75.59` are retrieved. And, the values of columns "C" and "E" are retrieved. If this explanation is not useful, I apologize.